# Given $f: X → Y$ and $g: X → Y$ are two functions. How to prove that if $f⊆g ⇒ f=g$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Definition $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = (y_1, y_2, ..., y_n) \Leftrightarrow x_1 = y_1, x_2=y_2, ..., x_n = y_n$
>
> Definition
>   $A_1 ×A_2×A_3 \cdots ×A_n =$ {$(a_1, a_2, ...a_n)| a_1 \in A_1, a_2 \in A_2, ..., a_n \in A_n$}
>
> Definition Let A and B be sets. A relation R from A to B is a subset of $A×B$.   Source: Discrete Mathematics, Susanna S. Epp
>
> Definition 2 $A⊆B≡∀x(x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B)$
>
> Definition 8. Let X and Y be sets. A function from X to Y is a triple (f, X, Y), where f is a relation from X to Y satisfying
>   (a) Dom(f) = X.
>   (b) If (x, y)$\in f$ and (x, z) $\in f$, then y=z.
>   We shall adhere to the custom of writing f: $X\space \rightarrow Y$ instead of (f, X, Y) and $y=f(x)$ instead of $(x,\space y) \in f$.
>
> [Question]Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: X\rightarrow Y$ be two functions with the same domain and the same codomain. Prove that if $f⊆g$, then $f=g$.
>   Source:Set Theory, You-Feng Lin.

The question looks ridiculous. The two functions' domains and codomains are the same X, Y respectively, so $f⊆X×Y$ and $g⊆X×Y$. f and g are the same relations.  But I tried to write a logical proof.

[My proof ] 
From the assumption, Dom(f)=Dom(g)=X, $f⊆X×Y$ and $g⊆X×Y$.
We have to show that $\forall (x, y) \in X×Y [(x, y) \in f \Leftrightarrow (x, y) \in g]$

i) $f⊆g ≡ \forall (x, y) \in X×Y [(x, y) \in f \Rightarrow (x, y) \in g]$

ii)
Now it's left to show that $\forall (x, y) \in X×Y [(x, y) \in g \Rightarrow (x, y) \in f]$ and I'm stuck on this step.
Can you show how to reach $\forall (x, y) \in X×Y [(x, y) \in g \Rightarrow (x, y) \in f]$?

[Added]
I'm not sure if I can get some hint from the proof of below theorem.
[image]

A first Course in Mathematical Logic and Set Theory by Michael L O'Leary

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Suppose that $\langle x,y\rangle\in g$; $x\in X=\operatorname{dom}f$, so there is some $y'\in Y$ such that $\langle x,y'\rangle\in f$. And $f\subseteq g$, so $\langle x,y'\rangle\in g$. Now use the fact that $g:X\to Y$ is a function, not just an arbitrary relation.

Comment: g is a relation from X to Y, i.e. g is a subset of A×B. Function is a triple. g is not a function. g: X→Y ⇔(g, X, Y) is a function.

Comment: @buzzee: I’m using the word *function* in its more usual sense. Use the property of $g$ that distinguishes it from an arbitrary relation from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Where in the question states that $g$ is a function? Can you quote that? You seem to be mistaking the relation g in "g:X→Y" as a functin.

Comment: @buzzee: I quote: ‘Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ be two ***functions*** with the same domain and same codomain’ [emphasis added].